# What is the maximum length of an Azure blob name

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

On Azure itself, I find I can make blobs with names of length 1000, but not 1100 (so I guess 1024).  Using dev storage I can do 200, but not 300 (so I guess something related to MAX_PATH).  Is there an official limit?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd135715.aspx:

> A blob name can contain any combination of characters, but reserved URL characters must be properly escaped. A blob name must be at least one character long and cannot be more than 1,024 characters long.
>
> The Azure Storage emulator supports blob names up to 256 characters long.

Answer (score 12):

Looking at the schema of "Blob" table in development storage database, the "BlobName" column is nvarchar(256) so I guess the limit is 256 characters for blob name in development storage.